# Cannot get time during PostgreSQL backup in Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, powershell

I am trying to use the following approach in order to backup PostgreSQL database that is in a Docker container:

```
cmd /c 'docker exec -t postgres-dev pg_dump dvdrental -U postgres -c -v > 
    C:\\postgresql\\backup\\dvdrental_%date:~-4,4%.%date:~-7,2%.%date:~-10,2%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.sql'
```

However, it gives the following file that has the size ok 0 KB and with the extension of `%tme`:

```
dvdrental_2021.05.24_%tme
```

I tried some different combinations, but it still the same and I am not able to get backup with the following format:

```
dvdrental_2021.05.24_15.30
```

So, how can I get the expected result as mentioned above? I use Windows, but I think it is not important as the command is executed on Docker container.

Comment: Is the docker container also running Windows or are you using one of the official postgres containers?

Comment: @Jeremy I use official postgres container

Comment: @Jeremy Any help pls?